# What are nameless entries in /proc/pid/smaps?

Tags: linux, memory, proc

I am trying to figure out what eats lots of memory in a process, therefore I tried reading `/proc/pid/smaps` (where pid is the pid of the process).

What boggles me is that some entries do not have names. For example:

```
4805d000-4805e000 rwxp 0001d000 00:0b 19674210   /lib/ld-2.6.so
Size:                  4 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   4 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         4 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
4805e000-4805f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:                  4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
4805f000-4885e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:               8188 kB
Rss:                8188 kB
Pss:                8188 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      8188 kB
Referenced:         8188 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Above, the first entry has name `/lib/ld-2.6.so`, but second and third do not have any name. So, what are those nameless entries? How to find out which library created them?

---

Out of curiosity, is there anything else (other then valgrind) to try to figure out what eats memory in a program?

---

After digging into kernel's code, I found out that these entries can indeed not be mapped to any file (fs/proc/task_mmu.c). But the question still stands: what are they? mmap() as a way to allocate memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nameless areas can be created via a sufficiently large `malloc`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *ip;
    char *before, *after;

    asprintf(&before, "cat /proc/%d/smaps > before", getpid());
    asprintf(&after, "cat /proc/%d/smaps > after", getpid());

    system(before);

    ip = malloc(9999999);
    if (!ip) abort();

    system(after);
    return 0;
}
```

As shown by

```
$ CFLAGS=-g make ilikebigmallocs
cc -g    ilikebigmallocs.c   -o ilikebigmallocs
$ ./ilikebigmallocs 
$ diff before after
64a65,80
> 7f97425ac000-7f9742f36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> Size:               9768 kB
> Rss:                   4 kB
...
```

so at least some of your areas were likely created by `malloc` or equivalent (which under the hood calls `mmap`). `strace` (or `sysdig`) can log these:

```
$ strace -e trace=memory -o blah ./ilikebigmallocs
$ awk '/^mmap/{print $NF}' blah
0x7fc6193b1000
0x7fc6193a6000
...
$ grep 7fc6193b1000 after
7fc6193b1000-7fc6193b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
$
```

I guess you could use `gdb` or a malloc tracer or other means to resolve a specific `mmap` back up to specific code in your memory-hungry process...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Found somewhere that memory allocation greater then 128k uses mmap(). Now I can't find the link to that article :(